# Silverstripe Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node

Tags: javascript, silverstripe

I am running version Silverstripe 3.0X. I have my few websites on Codero and all of them are working fine. I decided to move one to my new Amazon Linux Server. I was able to make everything work except for one.

When I got to admin side of my project for ex: http://illusion.info/admin/pages/, it loads fine and works fine. But when I try to navigate through ajax like clicking on other navigation link say settings or reports, I get some javascript error which is

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node.
fragment.appendChild(script);}}}
```

in http://illusion.info/assets/_combinedfiles/lib.js

I have no idea about this issue. How can I fix it or try to track it?

Comment: are you in dev-mode? Can you install xdebug to get a good backtrace? (be sure to de-activate it later on) Did you enable error logging?Can you see anything else when debugging ajax with e.g. firebug's network tab?

Comment: I tried dev-mode also, but there is no error. Firebug shows only these two lines of error which I mentioned above. I guess some server setting issue? because same is working well on Codero server.

Comment: You have the error only in live mode? And in browser console - it's a JS error, no PHP error?

Comment: Yes @wmk, I get error on both dev and live mode. But it seems to be a js error which I can see in console only and that also when I try to load page through ajax. When I load it normally like page reload it works fine and there is no error... I know its something weird and I too haven't seen it before.

Comment: I guess you're getting some data back from an AJAX call? I'd look at the response you're getting there…

Comment: @3dojo I check my server and node.js is not installed in it.. I mean I checked my /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/lib folders and only found python and ruby. Nothing related to Node..

Comment: Maybe try to delete your `assets/_combinedfiles` so those files can be recreated.

Comment: I tried that also so many times. I tried to track for error in SS errors in framework/sserrors/log but still no luck.. I am stuck at this point so bad..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have very old version of SS 3.0.x, please upgrade it to at least latest SS 3.0.14

The problem is in LeftAndMain.js

```
if(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')=='text/json') {
    newFragments=data;
} else {
    newFragments['Content']=data;
}
```

The actual response header is longer and does not match the condition

```
Content-Type:text/json;charset=UTF-8
```

It was fixed to be handled properly with

```
if(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type').match(/^text\/json[ \t]*;?/i)) {
```